# Calling Class.forName() twice

Tags: java, class, classloader

I am currently reading Class loader and their hierarchy functionality.
If I call below code -

```
ClassA a=  Class.forName("com.test.ClassA")
```

As per my understanding,now it will be initialized and loaded in memory with help of Application Class loader.
I have below questions:

1. What will happen if I call again call the above code? Will there be new instance created in memory for 'ClassA' or will it return the same loaded class reference?
2. If yes, as per this [post](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/12/how-classloader-works-in-java.html) of javarevisited,"**By using separate ClassLoader you can also loads same class from multiple sources and they will be treated as different class in JVM**" 
   What will be use of it?

Comment: BTW: `Class.forName` returns an Object of type `Class` and not an instance of the Class passed in the forName. `ClassA a=  Class.forName("com.test.ClassA")` is incorrect. It should be `Class a=  Class.forName("com.test.ClassA")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You will get the same class. Just test it. Load it a second time and check if `a1 == a2`.
2. The most frequent usage of this feature is probably in app servers: you can deploy several web applications in a single server, and all can use the same classes. But they shouldn't share static variables. And if one uses class Foo from library 1.0, and the other one uses class Foo from library 2.0, there should be no problem. Hence the need to load the same class with different class loaders.

Answer (score 1):

1. New instance is created only if you call:

   ClassA inst = new ClassA();

If you call Class.forName, the class definition (metadata and bytecode) is loaded into JVM, into special section of managed memory called HEAP. Usually, the applications use this function to preload class into JVM, so that later on there is no latency when application needs it.

2. The use is hotdeploy for example. You're debugging java web server. You find a mistake, and just want to change (reload) one class, not the whole application. Important point here is also "Different Class Loaders". That means that libraries in java can be loaded from different sources: jar, war (archives), from database, from network. Compare this to COM model of Windows, where library must be in same folder or /system32/ folder.